# Secure of Android app content

Tags: android, database, security

I created an Android app, and I'm ready to post it on playstore. But I'm not sure of secure of my app content.

The point is that I have a database inside of my app, and I don't want anyone to get info from it in any other way except through my app.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: If you want to give security for any password, then you can use MD5 algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is safe unless someone rooted his phone.

To make it more difficult to get the data in case of a rooted phone you could:

- host the database on a server where only your application has access (ssl client server authentication)
- encrypt the database content with a password stored in your application code (can be reverse engineered)

http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

bear in mind anyone with access to your application can reverse engineer it. You can make it more difficult by using a proguard.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

to obfuscate your decryption code.